# How to solve case sensitive issue in mysql VIEW

Tags: mysql, linux

My my.cnf config file is with:

```
lower_case_table_names = 2
```

so if table name is `"MyUsers"` it will take as it is.

but in view: i have used as a `"myusers"`.

in windows its working.

Now when i am trying to execute it(view) in linux server then it is saying `"myusers" doesnt exists.`

what is the problem in linux and its corresponding solution.

Not Duplicate:  As I clearly mentioned what I need and what I get. This is in view.

Comment: Never use upper case in tables name and your code is write it may be some other errors.

Answer (score -1):

MySQL users files for tables and views. The name of the files are identical to those of the tables as created. Windows is case-insensitive as far as addressing files is concerned. Linux is not, meaning that you can have the files `myfile.txt` and `Myfile.txt` at the same folder.

There is no way out (I learned this in the past as you are learning it now). You **MUST** use table/views names with the same case as they are defined. Column names, on the other hand, are case insensitive.

Comment: There is a way out, see the duplicate topic.

Comment: Thank you @Shadow. I wish I saw that long ago before I had to review my whole code (over 100 Stored Procedures/Functions) and correct the names of tables. In any case, I think that avoiding conversions and use a consistent naming policy is (at least my) preferred of going. Last, I humbly accept the punishment for my error (negative vote).

Comment: Yep, a consistent approach is a lot better. However, if you have to use both windows with Linux / unix to host MySQL servers, then you better op to have lower case table names. Actually, you may even tweak windows to use case sensitive file names (ntfs is a case sensitive file system).

Comment: means u r saying putting lower_case_table_names = 1; will solve the issue. how? If I want table name as "MyUsers" and in view mentioning as "myuser" will work? is it? but in that case table name itself is creating in small chars. then